# Removing trivial match clause in Coq

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

Consider the following example:

```
Definition cast {A : Set} (B : Set) (prf : A = B) (x : A)   : B.
  rewrite prf in x.
  refine x.
Defined.

Lemma castLemma0 {A : Set} : forall (x : A) prf, cast A prf x = x.
Proof.
  intros.
  compute.
???
```

After the compute step, we are left with the following context and subgoal

```
A : Set
x : A
prf : A = A
______________________________________(1/1)
match prf in (_ = y) return y with
| eq_refl => x
end = x
```

Clearly the left hand side and right hand side are equal. But I am not sure how to get rid of the annoying 'match' clause on the left hand side. In particular, trying to destruct prf yields the following error

```
Abstracting over the terms "A" and "prf"
leads to a term
fun (A0 : Set) (prf0 : A0 = A0) =>
match prf0 in (_ = y) return y with
| eq_refl => x
end = x which is ill-typed.
Reason is: In pattern-matching on term 
"prf0" the branch for constructor 
"eq_refl" has type "A" which should be 
"A0".
```

Is there a way to get rid of this match clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not provable in Coq without assuming an extra axiom, usually `eq_rect_eq` or something equivalent (Uniqueness of Identity Proofs (UIP) or Axiom K).

If you restrict `castLemma0` to the `eq_refl` case, that is `forall (x : A), cast A eq_refl x = x`, this is provable by reflexivity.

One way to understand why this is not provable, is to accept that it is consistant to assume an axiom `bool_eq_not : bool = bool` such that `cast bool bool_eq_not x = not x`.
Plugging in `bool_eq_not` for `prf` in `castLemma0` would imply that `not x = x`, which is certainly wrong.

Proving that this is possible requires demonstrating a model of type theory where `bool_eq_nat` is constructible. This was first done in the paper "The groupoid interpretation of type theory", by Martin Hofmann and Thomas Streicher. There have since been several other models, including a model in simplicial sets by Voevodsky, and several constructive models in cubical sets. These investigations are one aspect of the field of Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT).

---

As a side note, there is a somewhat recently added (and still experimental) feature [`SProp` (documentation)](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/sprop.html) that if you also `Set Definitional UIP` lets you prove this.

Comment: I appreciate your answer for giving a definitive answer on whether or not this is provable without extra axioms. However, I don't understand why the example given is a problem. I think I understand the reasoning, but I don't understand why I would accept that it is consistent to assume an axiom 

`cast bool bool_eq_not x = not x`

Comment: I added a paragraph giving some references to papers proving that `cast bool bool_eq_not x = not x` is consistent.

Comment: That definitely answers the question. Very interesting

Answer (score 2):

Because `prf` is an identifier, the `dependent destruction` tactic (from `Coq.Program.Equality`) can handle the dependency on `prf0` introduced by the convoy pattern. For example:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.

Lemma castLemma0 {A : Set} : forall (x : A) prf, cast prf x = x.
Proof.
  intros.
  compute.
  dependent destruction prf.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

(I don't know if `dependent destruction` relies on any new axioms under-the-hood, though—maybe someone else can help clarify.) **UPDATE:** OP found that it uses `eq_rect_eq` (≣ injectivity of dependent equality ≣ uniquness of identity proofs ≣ uniqueness of reflexive identity proofs ≣ axiom K, according to [Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.EqdepFacts.html)). Unfortunately, that makes this particular proof rather circular. Still, I'll leave this answer up in case others find it useful.

It's also worth noting that if you wanted to dependently destruct an *expression*, rather than just an identifier, that tactic and its relatives don't work anymore. I don't actually know the solution to this, or even if there is one in general. (For a more thorough discussion with those much more knowledgeable than me, see https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/.60dependent.20destruction.60.20of.20expressions/near/209916250.)

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. 

By using Print Assumptions castLemma0. It looks like this method does require the axiom

Eqdep.Eq_rect_eq.eq_rect_eq

which basically just states exactly what I am trying to prove (unfolded that is).

I am guessing since this is an axiom in the standard library, there is no way to prove this without it?

Comment: Edited, thanks! I honestly don't know if it can be avoided—we've officially reached the limit of my knowledge on the matter :-P

Comment: (With that said, if no one else answers here, I'm sure the Coq Zulip chat would be happy to help!)